# How to change/set priority of NSG rule using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, networking

how to create an PowerShell script to get lowest priority nsg rule in nsg group in azure and set the specific nsg priority according to the lowest priority.

Comment: No i want to get the nsg with the lowest priority!

Comment: Show us the code that you are working with.